# ElasticSearch fetch NULL values as empty string or "N/A"

Tags: elasticsearch, null, kibana

When i search for some document in elasticsearch, using GET /index/_search , I get the documents with some fields as null in them.
Ex:

```
"_source" : {
    "ClientReference" : null,
    "SenderMSISDN" : null,
}
```

But I want in such a way so that null values are displayed as 'N/A' or empty string "" , similar to what IFNULL() does in an sql query. Is it possible?
I've tried putting the mapping as the one below but this is not the solution

```
"ClientReference": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "null_value": "N/A"
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch will never modify the content of the source document you are indexing.

What `"null_value": "N/A"` does is that if `ClientReference` is null in your document, then ES will index `N/A` instead, but **the source document will still contain `"ClientReference": null`**.

The only way to modify a source document at indexing time is to leverage [ingest pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html)

For instance, you can create such a pipeline that will set `ClientReference` to `N/A` if it's null

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/unnullify
{
  "description" : "make sure to set default values to null fields",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "set" : {
        "if": "ctx.ClientReference == null",
        "field": "ClientReference",
        "value": "N/A"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then when you index your document, you need to specify the pipeline like this:

```
PUT my-index/_doc/1?pipeline=unnullify
{
    "ClientReference" : null,
    "SenderMSISDN" : null,
}
```

Doing so would modify the source document and index it like this:

```
{
    "ClientReference" : "N/A",
    "SenderMSISDN" : null,
}
```

If you're using Logstash to index your data you need to configure your `elasticsearch` output plugin to use the ingest pipeline, like this:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        ...
        pipeline => 'unnullify'
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay but in my case, i don't use PUT to index, indexing takes place through a logstash.conf. Do I need to add anything in the logstash.conf for that?

Comment: Thank you, I haven’t tried yet, will let you know if it works :)